# Scroll View и прокрутка фрагмента

Tags: android, android-fragment

Есть такой файл разметки фрагмента:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
     android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
     android:orientation="horizontal">

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/info_organisationName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="Фобос"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/info_favoriteImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" />
   </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/info_organisationInfo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="12" />
   </LinearLayout>

   <View
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:background="@color/lightgray" />

   <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout6"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/info_organisationAdress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Микр. АБ, д.8" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/info_buttonOnMap"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/button_onmap" />
   </LinearLayout>

   <View
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"

    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:background="@color/lightgray" />

   <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout7"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/info_listview_phones"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:elevation="3dp" />
   </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/info_explistview_timetable"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

   <View
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout8"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@color/lightgray" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/info_linearlayout_website"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_language_black_24dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/info_organisationWebsite"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:text="New Text" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/info_linearlayout_creditcard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_credit_card_black_24dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/info_organisationCard"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:text="" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Если вкратце, то корневой элемент это вертикальный `LinerLayout`, в котором поочередно компонуются вертикальные/горизонтальные `LinearLayout`, в некоторых имеется `ListView` и `ExpandableListView`, и `View`(разделитель в 1dp).

Есть файл разметки `Activity`, в котором есть `FrameLayout`, в который я запихиваю данный фрагмент:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/mainBackground"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/fragmentMainContainer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            </FrameLayout>
        </ScrollView>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_main"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start">

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Упорно не могу понять почему мой фрагмент не может прокручиваться. В чем тут ошибка: в неправильной разметке активити или фрагмента?

Первая картинка - тот момент когда все элементы еще влезают в экран.
Вторая - когда я раскрываю `ExpandableListView` и экран не начинает скролиться.
[image: Должно быть так]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вы вставляете прокручиваемый `View` (`ListIView`) в другой прокручиваемый `View` (`ScrollView`). В этом проблема. Система не понимает, что именно ей прокручивать. Это по определению неправильно.

Comment: А как было бы правильно? Тогда просто не нужно использовать ScrollView в разметке активити и вообще про него забыть?

Comment: Это уж вам решать. Изначально класть скролл в другой свролл - уже плохая идея. Есть ,конечно костыли, позволяющие это запустить, но я рекомендую вам пересмотреть архитектуру, и не пытаться изобрести велосипед из костылей

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо за совет, попробую помудрить, если что получится скину как ответ на свой же ответ.

Comment: А зачем использовать Scroll, когда можно использовать RecycleView и уже в каждом конкретном объекте использовать Scroll? Если записей много, то они жрут память, а для отображения нужно с 10 (все остальное пользователь все равно не видит).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

. Вы вкладываете в `ScrollView` сам контейнер фрагмента, для него будет высота == размеру экрана, а не размера вьюшек в фрагменте (для эксперимента `fragmentMainContainer` установите высоту к примеру 2000dp).
 2. Если вы хотите скролл в фрагменте, удалите обертку `ScrollView` у `fragmentMainContainer` и замените у файла разметке рут контейнер `LinearLayout` на `ScrollView`

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    //..........
    </ScrollView>
```

3. После такой замены, ListView и ExpandableListView нужно будет программно выставлять высоту.
4. Более верный вариант это сделать кастомный адаптер для `ExpandableListView`. Судя по скрину это возможно. И `ScrollView` можно будет не использовать.

**UPD**

https://github.com/anandbose/ExpandableListViewDemo

По этой ссылке лежит пример. Расширьте класс `Item`.

1. Добавьте `enum` вместо `int type` и расширьте его для таких параметров как телефон и т.д.
2. В `onBindViewHolder` по енуму и данным меняйте `view` как вам угодно (стили, цвета) вставляйте текст через `Spannable`, делайте невидимым не нужные `view`.

Comment: Скоро попробую, а можно поподробнее о кастомном адаптере, а вернее, что в нем нужно изменить или добавить. Просто сам адаптер есть, наследуюсь от BaseExpadableAdapter.

Comment: Вечером я скину пример.

Comment: Хорошо, отпишусь по тому, что вы написали, выполнил все включая пункт 3, помогло, экран скоолится, но для моего приложения это неприемлимо. Тоесть у меня есть динамический ListView, в котором может быть n-ое кол-во записей. Статичный размер высоты не позволяет отобразить все данные. С ExpandableListView другая история, при задании статичной высоты, независимо от того, раскрыта ли группа или нет, он захватывает все это пространство, и при свернутой группе, он отображает пустое место под группой, получается некрасиво.

Comment: Нужно, чтобы при раскрытии группы он, как бы расширялось пространство под группой для детей. Впринципе, я так думаю можно при загрузке фрагмента, программно определять место для ListView в зависимости от кол-ва элементов, а для RxpandableListView, сначала определить высоту при закрытом состоянии, а в адаптере в методе отвечающем за раскрытие группы, прописать изменение высоты при раскрытом состоянии. Или это плохой подход?

Comment: высота в первом пункте была для эксперимента. естественно fragmentMainContainer должен иметь высоту match_parent, а вот у файла разметки достаточно иметь всего 1 ExpandableListView, естественно все что видно на представленном экране должно быть в нем. Но все складывается нужды. и все зависит от того "что" вы хотите скролить. все полностью, или только часть экрана (списки). отсюда и пойдут решения.

Comment: Лично я бы использовал 1 ExpandableListView на все. Сделать Generic  List из нужных данный и пихнуть в кастомный адаптер, в зависимости от типа данных рисовать вью

Comment: Тоесть, вы предлагаете то, чтобы каждый элемент ListView представлялся как нераскрываемая группа  в новом ExpandableListView, и последней группой был бы "перенесенный" изначальный ExpandableListView?

Comment: Добавил ссылку в ответ

Comment: Спасибо за наводку, пару часов посидел, вроде разобрался и даже получилось. Конечно это не прямое решение той проблемы, но отличное "перенаправление" на другое решение)

Answer (score 1):

Я столкнулся с той же проблемой. Только в моем случае у меня в наличии внутри ScrollView благодаря дизайнеру оказались ListView, GridView и WebView со скроллом и зумом яндекс-карт. Плюс некоторые фрагменты должны были иметь кнопки в самом низу экрана (`android:fillViewport`) и при появлении клавиатуры кнопки должны были подниматься вверх. Извел кучу времени, но вроде победил:

Раздвигать высоту всех списков я не стал - это плохая идея. Так может и памяти не хватить. Все внутренние скролящиеся элементы (и webview в том числе) расширяются примерно вот таким образом:

```
public class GridViewScrollable extends GridView {

    /* Здесь конструкторы с вызовами super.xxx */

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev){
        // Запрет на перехват событий касания вышестоящими элементами
        // в Kitkat проблема уже решена и там все работает, так что 
        // перехват не будем запрещать. Запрет отправляется только при 
        // касании элемента - тогда отслеживание ускорения работает нормально
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
           if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
               requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }
}
```

Это предотвращает кражу touch-событий внешним ScrollView и решает проблему скролинга, но создает другую проблему - свайп меню с левой стороны перестает работать потому что Drawer теперь тоже не может перехватить события касаний. Чтобы победить это надо сделать layout-барьер для `requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)` чуть выше ScrollView:

```
public class DisallowInterceptBarrier extends LinearLayout {

    /* Здесь конструкторы с вызовами super.xxx */

    @Override
    public void requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {
        // Не делаем вызов super.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent()
        // и соответственно запрет выше не пойдет. Если Kitkat и выше
        // то запреты пропускаем.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
           super.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(disallowIntercept);
        }        
    }
}
```

Тестирование вроде побочек никаких не выявило, но возможно они и есть. Лучше всего было бы как-то узнавать в обработчике onInterceptTouchEvent() внутри расширенного ScrollView, что перехваченные события идут от скролящегося элемента и не трогать их (возвращать false), но сделать это у меня так и не получилось.